# Adding item to array

Tags: android

I have a leagueList array. This array is then sorted by points and goal difference.

What I need to do is to add post the sort below the league ranking (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc...) and the league could contain 8 teams or 32 teams.

```
leagueList.sort(Comparator.comparing(league_List::getPoints).thenComparing(league_List::getGoalDiff));
Collections.reverse(leagueList);
league_lv_adapter adapter = new league_lv_adapter (getActivity(), leagueList);
listViewLeague.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adding in the ranking would need to happen after I've reserved the array and before and passing it into the adapter.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

One idea I had was to create a second array with the teams passed in to the second array in the correct order and then adding in a loop per addition that adds in the rank. It should work but seems very inelegant and before implementing that I want to see if anyone had any creative ideas on achieving the same thing.

Comment: can you explain what you need in more details, please?
Do you want to display the array as a list in adapter and display the rank on each item? for example (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc...)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. So at present the list displays fine (without any ranking, as the list itself is dumb to any ranking). I need to display the ranking alongside each record once they've been sorted. Another approach was to do a count on the array and run a basic loop after on a separate list for ranking but that seems very poor.

Comment: the rank depends on what? does your league object has a field rank?

Comment: The rank is dependant on points (the array is sorted by the largest points total first, etc...) and then a second sort by goal difference which is in the object as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to implement the ranking. In the Array Adapter, the method for getting the view passes in an integer position.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
```

And as Java uses zero based arrays, I just had to add 1;

```
Integer rank = position + 1;
```